# Managing version numbers in a custom Gradle Plugin

Tags: gradle

I'm developing a custom gradle plugin. At the top of the `build.gradle` file of the plugin I specify the plugin's version number:

`version '0.1.3'`

I have a number of Gradle projects that I use during my custom plugin's unit and integration testing phase. For each of these projects, I have to declare my custom plugin's jar as a dependency in the project's `build.gradle` file . For example:

`classpath files('libs/UmpleGradlePlugin-0.1.3.jar')`

Ideally, I'd have the version number written in one place rather than explictly writing it in every test project I use. To that end, I've created a constants file, `Constants.java`, that includes `static final string VERSION_NUMBER = "0.1.3"`. I want to use `VERSION_NUMBER` in the build files of my projects rather than rather than writing the version number explicitly.

I've compiled `Constants.java` and added `Constants.class` to the `classpath`. However, when I try to use `Constants.VERSION_NUMBER` in a `build.gradle` file, Gradle thinks I'm trying to use a property that doesn't exist:

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Could not find property 'Constants' on root project 'UmpleGradlePlugin'.`

How can I use `VERSION_NUMBER` in a build file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the class from build.gradle, you have to add it as a **buildscript** dependency:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('libs/UmpleGradlePlugin-0.1.3.jar')
    }
}
```

And after you can use it directly from build.gradle. For example:

```
println("pi = ${Math.PI}") // works and prints static variable.
println("2 * pi = ${java.lang.Math.PI}") // works fine too
```

I think line "import com.package.Constants" isn't required, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: I want to use a class *in* `build.gradle`. I want to use the `VERSION_NUMBER` field from `Constants.java` inside `build.gradle`.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I meant that you can use class *in* build.gradle if you add it as buildscript dependency.

Comment: Oh! That's handy, thanks for the clarification. Can I include a single class file instead of a `.jar`? Maybe something like `classpath files('Math.class')`? I just have one file with version information that I need.

Comment: I have tried now. For example: /dir/com/package/Constants.class, then classpath files('dir') and in build.gradle should be line "import com.package.Constants.class"

P.S. You can just read version from simple text file instead of loading java class. Something like 'version = new File(filename).text'